# Laravel check if route is api or web

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

How can I check wether the middleware is web or auth.
Following Returns all routes, but I want to divide between api and web.

```
$routes = app()->routes->getRoutes();
foreach($routes as $routeKey => $routeValue)
{
    dd($routeValue);
}
```

returns this:

```
Route {#109 ▼
  +uri: "oauth/authorize"
  +methods: array:2 [▶]
  +action: array:6 [▼
    "middleware" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "web"
      1 => "auth"
    ]
    "uses" => "\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize"
    "controller" => "\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize"
    "namespace" => "\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers"
    "prefix" => "oauth"
    "where" => []
  ]
  +controller: null
  +defaults: []
  +wheres: []
  +parameters: null
  +parameterNames: null
  +computedMiddleware: null
  +compiled: CompiledRoute {#203 ▶}
  #router: Router {#21 ▶}
  #container: Application {#3 ▶}
}
```

Comment: Api routes are prefixed, but why would you want to find out rather than to be sure: 2 middlewares...?

Answer (score 7):

I found two ways of telling if the request comes from the API:

you can check if the route has an "api" prefix (seems cleaner)

```
$is_api_request = $request->route()->getPrefix() === 'api';
```

Or check if it has the "api" request middleware

```
$is_api_request = in_array('api',$request->route()->getAction('middleware'));
```

Tested on Laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet if your API accept JSON. Note it won't work for other than JSON like XML, YAML, plain text, html etc.,

```
$msg = config('constants.messages.MSG001');
if ($request->wantsJson()) { //Here we check if the request wants response in JSON

  $response = ['success' => FALSE, 'message' => $msg];
  return response($response);
} else { //If request don't wants JSON we redirect it to login page with message.

  Auth::logout();
  return redirect('/login')->with('error', $msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

1 . Get all routes and return them into your view:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $routes = app()->routes->getRoutes();
    return view ('api.doc.index',compact('routes'));
}
```

2 . Run through a foreach check wether the prefix is correct and display them:

```
            @foreach ($routes as $routeKey => $routeValue)
                @if($routeValue->getPrefix() == 'api')
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$routeValue->uri}}</td>
                    <td>{{$routeValue->getName()}}</td>
                    <td>{{$routeValue->getPrefix()}}</td>
                    <td>{{$routeValue->getActionMethod()}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```